# camel weaveAddLast() in before() will add many copies, not good

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, apache-camel

Am I the first one bumping into this? Is there a way I've overseen to reset the loaded context without writing too much code?

Problem:

```
@Before
public void before() throws Exception {
    context.getRouteDefinition(MyRoute.ID).adviceWith(context, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            weaveAddLast().to("seda:endjob");
        }
    });
}
@Test
public void testOne(){}
@Test
public void testTwo(){}
```

will add the "seda:endjob" endpoint TWICE - one for each @Test because @Before will be called before every one. So it kind of makes sense, but I definitely hate it! ALL the examples I've been able to find, either have only one @Test (duh no problem) or do the weaving INSIDE the test which again avoids the problem (but repeats code if my weaving gets hairy)

What I do now is wrapping the weaving into many ugly custom checks, like this one:

```
        if (getOriginalRoute().getOutputs().size() == 1) {
            weaveAddLast().to("seda:endjob");
        }
```

The question is then, is there a good way to reset the weaving? Or reload the RouteBuilder? Or something else, just without extra code?

Comment: Check out the @DirtiesContext annotation. This will restart the context after each test.

Comment: I'm testing with Arquillian in WildFly, while the @DirtiesContext is a Spring test extension. Won't help here...